# Facebook tabs ssl minimum requirement

Tags: facebook, encryption, ssl, tabs, minimum

I would know which is the minimal requirement for ssl certificates to use with facebook tabs. I mean, there are many different kind of certificates: encryption bits, extended validation or not, and so on....

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum requirement from facebook, as long as the page is served over SSL the certificate can even be self signed.

However, the users browser will check for a valid signing authority for the certificate and if it can't find one it will issue a warning for the user and advise them not to continue.

A standard SSL cert from a certified CA will be fine for most facebook app purposes.